# Why does onCreate called twice in my Fragment when I first time open Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an AsyncTask class in my fragment and it must execute only once on each fragment `onActivityCreated` called. But in the `onCreate` fragment method I have a log message about number of what page is showing now. But I can't understand why this message is telling me that number of page is 0 and 1 instantly when I open `Activity` at first time. Hope somebody could help.

```
public class ScheduleActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
static final String TAG = "myLogs";
static final int PAGE_COUNT = 9;


ViewPager pager;
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.schedule_view);


    final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.new_nav_bg));
    background.setTileModeX(android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(background);


    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerS);
 //   pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onPageSelected, position = " + position);


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                                   int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
}

private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ScheduleFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }
  }
}
```

Fragment class

```
public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {

static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";

int pageNumber;

private ArrayList<PlistItem> schedList = null;
private ListView listSched = null;
public CustomSheduleItem adapter;
int date;





static ScheduleFragment newInstance(int page) {
    ScheduleFragment ScheduleFragment = new ScheduleFragment();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
    ScheduleFragment.setArguments(arguments);
    return ScheduleFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);

    Log.w("page number", "" + pageNumber);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view;


    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_fragment, null);


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    TextView schedDate = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.dateSched);
     date = 23 + pageNumber;
    String sDate = Integer.toString(date);
    schedDate.setText("    " + sDate);
    String jsonString = getResources().getString(R.string.scheduleJson);
    new DownloadFilesTask().execute(jsonString);



}

public void updateList() {
    listSched = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listSched);



    adapter = new CustomSheduleItem(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), schedList);
    listSched.setAdapter(adapter);


}

private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (null != schedList) {
            updateList();

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String jsonString = params[0];


        //         JSONObject json = getJSONFromUrl(url);
        InputStream is = null;
        JSONObject jObj = null;
        String json = null;

        is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shedule);

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"), 8);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        json = sb.toString();


        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }



        parseJson(jObj);
        return null;
    }
}







public void parseJson(JSONObject jObj) {
    try {


        //   if (json.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {

        JSONArray schedule = jObj.getJSONArray(""+date+"");

        Log.w("SCHEDULE", "" + schedule);

        schedList = new ArrayList<PlistItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < schedule.length(); i++) {
            Log.w("LENGTH", "" + schedule.length());
            JSONObject day = (JSONObject) schedule.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.w("DAY", "" + day);
            for (int j=1; j<day.length()+1;j++) {
                JSONObject row = (JSONObject)day.getJSONObject(""+j+"");
                Log.w("ROW",""+row);
                PlistItem item = new PlistItem();
                item.setPlace(row.getString("place"));
                item.setTimeOne(row.getString("time1"));
                item.setTimeTwo(row.getString("time2"));
                item.setText(row.getString("text"));


                schedList.add(item);

            }
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

LogCat messages:

```
08-15 18:44:36.716    5697-5697/com.project1.2014 W/page number﹕ 0
08-15 18:44:36.720    5697-5697/com.project1.2014 W/page number﹕ 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viewpagers preload pages to allow for that seamless transition.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
>
> This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number
>   of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in
>   place on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in
>   perceived smoothness of paging animations and interaction. If you have
>   a small number of pages (3-4) that you can keep active all at once,
>   less time will be spent in layout for newly created view subtrees as
>   the user pages back and forth.
>
> You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex
>   layouts. ***This setting defaults to 1***.

Take note of the highlighted content. This would be the reason you are getting two fragments loaded at once.